# Alpha-beta pruning in Common Lisp

Tags: artificial-intelligence, common-lisp, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I tried coding Alpha-beta using the pseudocode found in Wikipedia. After the program reaches `(EQ depth 0)` it returns the heuristic value but depth continues deacreasing causing a cycle. Right now my code looks like this:

```
(defun ab(tab node depth a b)
(cond ((EQ depth 0) (calculaH tab))
        ((eq (mod depth 2) 0) (setq v -999999) (setq movimiento (sigMov depth node tab))  (loop while (not(null movimiento))  
                                                        do (setq v (max v (ab (nth 3 movimiento) movimiento (- depth 1) a b)))
                                                           (setq a (max a v))
                                                           (cond((<= b a) (break))
                                                                (t (setq movimiento (sigMov depth movimiento tab))))) (return v))

        (t (setq v 999999) (setq movimiento (sigMov depth node tab)) (loop while (not(null movimiento))   
                                                        do (setq v (min v (ab (nth 3 movimiento) movimiento (- depth 1) a b)))
                                                           (setq a (min b v))
                                                           (cond((<= b a) (break))
                                                                (t (setq movimiento (sigMov depth movimiento tab))))) (return v))))
```

Should I increase depth value somwhere in my code? Why doesn´t the recursion increases the value by itself?

Comment: Jorge: the problem is that your code is hard to read and difficult to understand. It's not readable formatted and full of undefined variables. Who knows what it is doing and why and when it works by accident.

Comment: Maybe you will like to use [Portacle](https://portacle.github.io/) ? It is a multiplatform and portable CL environment (shipping Emacs, SBCL, Slime, Quicklisp and Git) so it will automatically indent your code correctly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [alpha-beta prunning algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning#Pseudocode) on Wikipedia can be translated into  Lisp almost as-is. Since it uses infinite values, let's not hack around with "999999" but define `min` and `max` functions that work reliably with those special values:

```
(defpackage :alphabeta
  (:use :cl)
  ;; custom min/max functions that support infinity
  (:shadow min max))

(in-package :alphabeta)

(defvar -∞ '-∞ "Negative infinity symbol")
(defvar +∞ '+∞ "Positive infinity symbol")

(defun min (a b)
  (cond
    ((eql a +∞) b)
    ((eql b +∞) a)
    ((eql a -∞) -∞)
    ((eql b -∞) -∞)
    (t (cl:min a b))))

(defun max (a b)
  (cond
    ((eql a -∞) b)
    ((eql b -∞) a)
    ((eql a +∞) +∞)
    ((eql b +∞) +∞)
    (t (cl:max a b))))
```

The code also relies on auxiliary functions, which I declare here to avoid warnings:

```
 ;; You need to implement the followning functions
(declaim (ftype function terminal-node-p heuristic-value children))
```

Then, the pseudo-code can be written nearly identically. For the sake of this question, I kept the same greek variables, but as pointed out by Dan Robertson in comments, this might lead to surprises:

> One thing to be wary of when using names like α or β is that a typical Unicode-aware lisp implementation will upcase them into Α and Β. Can you tell the difference between A and Α or B and Β?

```
(defun alphabeta (node depth α β maximizing-player-p)
  (when (or (= depth 0) (terminal-node-p node))
    (return-from alphabeta (heuristic-value node)))
  (if maximizing-player-p
      (let ((value -∞))
        (dolist (child (children node))
          (setf value (max value (alphabeta child (1- depth) α β nil)))
          (setf α (max α value))
          (when (<= β α)
            ;; β cut-off
            (return)))
        value)
      (let ((value +∞))
        (dolist (child (children node))
          (setf value (min value (alphabeta child (1- depth) α β t)))
          (setf α (min α value))
          (when (<= β α)
            ;; α cut-off
            (return)))
        value)))
```

- **Never compare numbers with [`EQ`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_eq.htm)**. Use [`=`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eq_sle.htm#EQ) if you expect to compare only numbers.
- **Always introduce local variables with `let`**, never `setq` a variable which is not defined in current scope. Your code fails because your Lisp implementation define global variables the first time you call `setq` on unbound symbols. After that, you mutate global variables in your recursive code, which make it dysfunctional.
- Do not have overlong lines (this is true in most languages), **indent properly**, put each new form on its own line starting at the same indentation.
- **[`BREAK`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_break.htm) in Lisp *enters the debugger***. If you want to exit a loop early, use [**`RETURN`**](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_return.htm) (this works because iteration constructs like [`DO`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/m_do_do.htm) introduce implicit  [`BLOCK`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_block.htm)s named `nil`).

Comment: One thing to be wary of when using names like `α` or `β` is that a typical Unicode-aware lisp implementation will upcase them into `Α` and `Β`. Can you tell the difference between `A` and `Α` or `B` and `Β`?

Comment: @DanRobertson You are right, I'll leave a note in the answer. Thanks.